# Cannot assign string from array to the int

Tags: java

I have written the following line of code that reads the data in a text file and stores it in a array. Everything works fine except for when I try and convert the `String` into `int`.

Here I am trying to scan the text file line by line and store every word separated by comma in an array. I cant figure out why its throwing `NumberFormatException` when I convert `String` into `int` and assign it to `int id`.

The following is the code I have written:

```
public boolean loadPapers(){
    String fileName = "paper.txt"; // file to be opened
    boolean fileOpened = true;
    int id, rank;
    String topic, author, date;

    try {
        Scanner fileData = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        while(fileData.hasNextLine()){
            String line = fileData.nextLine();

            String[] words = line.split(","); // Separate words from sentence


            // get required parameters for Paper object
            id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);  // throws numberFormatException
            topic = words[1];
            author = words[2];
            date = words[3];
            rank = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);  // throws numberFormatException

            // create new paper
            Paper entry = new Paper(id, topic, author, date, rank);
            paperList.add(entry);

        } // end while

        fileData.close(); // close file
    }  // end try

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        fileOpened = false;
        swingErrorMessage("ERROR: File couldn't be opened.\nNo papers were loaded.", "File Error");
    } // end catch

    return fileOpened;

} // end loadPapers
```

The following is the content of text file:

```
46,Evolutionary Comp,Michael Smith,12/01/10,4
61,Fuzzy Logic and App,John Peterson,13/01/10,3
118,Neural Networks,Arthur London,20/01/10,5 
200,Evolutionary Comp,Scott Jones,30/01/10,1 
210,Fuzzy Logic and App,Joe Wang,01/02/10,4 
12,Evolutionary Comp,Andy Roberts,12/12/12,3 
123,Computer Science,Zhou You,12/12/12,3
```

The line that program fails on is:

```
id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);  // throws numberFormatException
```

The error message looks like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at PaperManagerApplication.Frame.loadPapers(Frame.java:409)
at PaperManagerApplication.PaperManager.main(PaperManager.java:16)
```

Comment: Can you please print out `words[0]` and `words[4]` so that we can see the String content that your program fails on?

Comment: The program fails on while printing id and throws NumberFormatException.

Comment: I would suggest for you to print the values of the array after it has split them and you will probably find the answer quick - LEAVE THE ID AS STRING AND PRINT.. AND YOU WILL SEE.

Comment: It prints the value. Problem is only when I try to assign it as int.

Comment: What is the value?  Are there any "funny chars" like spaces, tabs etc.

Comment: I think the exception is clear, there is a space before or after the splitted number.. as the solution below suggests first get the value of the string in word[0], trim() it and then try parsing it to int

Comment: For better readability, dont parse integer `id` and `rank` the loop, instead do it in the `Paper` constructor. You code will be cleaner and more reusable that way.

Comment: Add a System.out.println(line); to see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: @user710502 I have tried it already. still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not clean, trim it first.

Comment: What about your input file? Are there any blank or empty lines, perhaps at the bottom or top of the file?

Comment: so could you please explain what that statement does.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you print the array words to see what split did?  Also, beware of spaces in the `String`s - you should usually call `trim()` before `parseInt()`.

Looking at your just added stack trace, it's barfing on an empty `String`.  Add a `System.out.println(line)` to see which line is causing the problem.

Comment: so how do you write it. I have already tried writing id = Integer.parseInt(words[0].trim()); still doesn't work.

Comment: Trim it first, then try parsing it.. string temp = word[0].Trim();, int id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

Answer (score 1):

The key is here: `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

The problem you have is that you either have an empty line in your input e.g.

```
123,Computer Science,Zhou You,12/12/12,3
<empty line here just before end of file>
```

Or you have an empty parameter e.g.

```
,Computer Science,Zhou You,12/12/12,3
```

Effectively, your code is fine except that it doesn't handle the above two cases.

Comment: Its doesn't have any empty line nor any empty spaces.

Comment: Put in a debug statement to print the value of `line`, then let us know what that value is for *the line that fails*.

Answer (score 1):

you can just execute a statement which will remove all the char other than digits:

```
word[4]= word[4].replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" ); avoid all the non-digits chars.
Integer.parseInt(word[4]);
```